# How to copy a command from history?

Tags: sed, awk, history

I try to copy a command from history. How can I copy the 510th command? Please, see the data below. My bet is:

```
history | grep 510 | sed '1q;d' | awk '{print $2-$10}' | pbcopy
```

but the output is 0. I cannot understand the reason. What is wrong in the command?

```
  505  find . -perm=750 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
  506  find . --perm=750 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
  507  find . -perm=750 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
  508  find . -perm=750 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
  510  find . -perm 750 -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
  512  history | grep perm 750 -print0 | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using bash:

```
echo "!510" | pbcopy
```

(See also "history expansion" in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction))

Comment: @UnixBasics: Don't try to use that without quotes, it will hurt you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl to print everything but the first column (`510`) of the requested line:

```
history | perl -ane 'print "@F[1..$#F]" if($F[0]==510)'
```

Answer (score 1):

For a range of fields in Awk, you need a for-loop.  What you're doing is subtraction, thus the result of zero.

Usually the cut command does the task of extracting columns, but sometimes Awk is more appropriate.

Here's what you meant.

```
history | grep 510 | sed 1q \
 | awk '{for(i = 2; i <= NF; i++){ORS = (i == NF ? "\n" : " "); print $i;}}' \
 | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `$2` and `$10` are not numbers in the awk scripts. The fields' indexes are 1-based, so if you want the `750`, the first one is `$5`, the second one is `$11`.

Note that this is different with the lines with "`-perm=750`"

Comment: I think the person wants a range of fields, and not subtraction.  Stunning coincidence, though!